# Audit deep associations with Rails Audited gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-audited

I have the next three models:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :subjects, dependent: :destroy
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited associated_with: :school
  has_associated_audits

  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited associated_with: :attachable
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Basically, A `school` has many `subjects`, and each `subject` has many `attachments` (the `attachment` model is polymorphic because it's used for other models too, just in case it matters...)

The problem is that the audit is not working as I expect. I create a school, then a subject for that school, and then I add attachments to that subject. This is what I get from the console:

```
School.last.associated_audits # => returns only changes on Subjects, not on subject's attachments.
Subject.last.associated_audits # => returns only changes associated to its attachments
```

But I would need is `School.last.associated_audits` to include attachments audited changes too.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you say, it's not working ***as you expect***. That's not to say it isn't working.

What is the problem you're looking to solve? Are you trying to display all `School`, `Subject` and `Attachment` audits together?

Comment: @Tass Exactly, I want to display all together.

Answer (score 4):

While you're not able to retrieve audits from deep associations, you could  group the audits together. For example:

```
school = School.find(params[:id])
audits = school.audits + school.associated_audits
school.subjects.each { |subject| audits += subject.associated_audits }
```

I believe this should give you the entire collection of audits for `School`, `Subject` and `Attachments`. Is this sort of what you were after?

Answer (score 2):

The audited gem now has a helper method:

> You can access records' own audits and associated audits in one go:

```rb
company.own_and_associated_audits
```